# URL string parameter to choose specific HTML Tab and add some text

Tags: html, url, parameters, tabs

Getting my head banging since this morning to do this simple (I think) thing:

I want to create a link (manually) that automatically selects the third Tab and adds some text to this webpage:

[http://www.acessibilidade.gov.pt/accessmonitor/](http://www.acessibilidade.gov.pt/accessmonitor)

I've tried some ways, including http://www.acessibilidade.gov.pt/accessmonitor/?#form3 but to no avail... what I am really missing here? Is even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have access to be able to edit that page?

Comment: @hairmot: I presume that the OP wants to navigate to the page, with the third tab's form prefilled with some information from the user.

Comment: That's right hairmot. And, no, I do not have permission to edit the page... the webpage isn't mine either. I just to want to create some links in a Word Document that by clicking by other users, it will go off that page, select the third tab and adds some little text.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have access to edit this page's source code then you cannot do what you are suggesting with a simple url or querystring value.

If you could edit the page then you could add some JavaScript or server side code to  open the tab you specify in the query string/url.

Fancier solutions include proxying the site and injecting your own javascript or simply re-writing the html but this isn't really recommended as any such solution would be very fragile and the owner of the original site may not be too happy with you doing that.

You could also use a browser automation tool like selenium.

Comment: So, as I was thinking, this is not possible at all. I do not want to use injection code nor other automation tool.